# Java creating nativequery with list of bytearray

Tags: java, sql, java-7, nativequery

Hi i am trying to pass list of `byteArray` to a SQL query but my code doesn't work.

```
public List<Message> findAll(List<byte[]> ids) {
    String sqlString = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID in (" + StringUtils.join(ids, ',') + ")";    
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sqlString).setParameter(1, ids); 
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? "_but my code doesn't work_" is a bit too vague.. What doesn't work? Does the `StringUtils.join` not work with your List of byte-arrays? Does the generated query-String not work when you directly try this query on your database? Does the `query.getResultList()` give an error? Or does it not give any results at all? I assume it's the first one, since joining a list of byte-arrays will probably use the default `toString` of the byte-array. What is your input list; what is your expected resulting query-String; and what is your current incorrect query-String?

Comment: hi, i get  SqlSyntaxErrorException: ILLEGAL SYMBOL "[". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: ARRAY ROW NEXTVAL PREVVAL NEXT PREVIOUS <CHARSTRING>. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.21.29
ERRORCODE:-104

Comment: Current SQLString: "sqlString" SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID in ([B@a0321451,[B@d93b2fb4)

Comment: What is in the byte array? Is it (byte-sized) numeric ids of records? What do you expect the select to look like?

This all looks a bit fishy to me, since you seem to try to select from mytable where the id is one of the ids in the list - but each id in the list is only a byte, your database seems to support only 256 characters.

Additionally I'm never a fan of constructing SQL query strings on the fly (to prevent SQL injection, which is not an issue with byte[] but anyways ... eeeek!)

Answer (score 0):

Your ids is a list of byte arrays (i.e., it has two dimensions). The `StringUtils.join` method doesn't work with that. Plus you don't need to set arrays as a parameter as you haven't specified any parameters in your query.

If you output your SQL string you will see that it is not at all correct.

You will have to flatten out your list of arrays first before using it. Someone can probably do this with streams in one line of code, but an easier way is to use a for loop and a new array.

I haven't tested this, but something like:

```
List<Strings> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (byte[] idArray : ids) {
    list.add(StringUtils.join(idArray, ','); // join each array
}
String all = StringUtils.join(list, ','); // join all of the arrays
```